# Get XML values from string using Python

Tags: python

I would like to identify all TIMEX3 values inside a string using Python. For example, if my string is:

```
 Ecole Polytechnique, maar hij bleef daar slechts tot <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="1888">1888</TIMEX3>. 
 Daarna had hij een korte carriere bij het leger als officier d'artillerie in <TIMEX3 tid="t6" type="DATE" value="1889">1889</TIMEX3>
```

I would like to get back the list

```
 ["1888", "1889"]
```

So far I tried converting to a tree using the xml.eTree.ElementTree, but this crashes on my data with a parse error - not well formed, invalid token message. I am thinking that maybe I could avoid this using a regular expression? Any help much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: where is this data coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''Ecole Polytechnique, maar hij bleef daar slechts tot <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="1888">1888</TIMEX3>. 
 Daarna had hij een korte carriere bij het leger als officier d'artillerie in <TIMEX3 tid="t6" type="DATE" value="1889">1889</TIMEX3>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> [i.text for i in soup.find_all('timex3')]
['1888', '1889']
>>> [i['value'] for i in soup.find_all('timex3')]
['1888', '1889']
>>> [i['value'] for i in soup.find_all('timex3') if i.has_attr("value")]
['1888', '1889']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems to work, with the only difference that i.text doesn't always return me the value specified inside the xml tag. How can I get that value instead of the text contained inside the xml?

Comment: try `[i.string for i in soup.find_all('timex3')]`

Comment: This seems to behave just like i.text, returns exactly the same values

Comment: Found it: it's i["value"]

Comment: If value does not exist you will get a keyError

Comment: `[i['value'] for i in soup.find_all('timex3') if i.has_attr("value")]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regular expression, you can do this :

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """
... Ecole Polytechnique, maar hij bleef daar slechts tot <TIMEX3 tid="t5" type="DATE" value="1888">1888</TIMEX3>. 
...  Daarna had hij een korte carriere bij het leger als officier d'artillerie in <TIMEX3 tid="t6" type="DATE" value="1889">1889</TIMEX3>"""
>>> result = re.findall(r'value="([\d]+)', s)
>>> result
['1888', '1889']
>>>
```

but using BeautifulSoup as exemplified by Avinash Raj it could work better .